How can we delete a failed round from range in rock/paper/scissor?
I have written a code for this game and I have written range for it that do this code for 5 times and then ask about our decision that if we want to continue or not but when I run it in terminal and write another word except s,p,r it counts this round too and the game will run for 4 times.

from random import randint
game_choices = {
    'r': "rock",
    'p': "paper",
    's': 'scissor'
}
player_score = 0
pc_score = 0

for i in range(5):  
    player = input('please enter your choose from s(scissor),r(rock),p(paper):')
    if player not in ['s', 'r', 'p']:
        print('not a valid input!')

    print('your choice is ' + game_choices[player])
    choices = ['s', 'r', 'p']
    random_number = randint (0, 2)
    pc = choices[random_number]
    print('computer choice is ' + game_choices[pc])
    if player == pc:
        print('_-_-_-_')
        print('equaled')
    elif player == 's':
        if pc == 'r':
            print('_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_')
            print("!computer win! score it's for computer!")
            pc_score += 1
        else:
            print('_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_')
            print("!you win! score it's for you!")
            player_score += 1
    elif player == 'r':
        if pc == 'p':
            print('_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_')
            print("!computer win! score it's for computer!")
            pc_score += 1
        else:
            print('_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_')
            print("!you win! score it's for you!")
            player_score += 1
    elif player == 'p':
        if pc == 's':
            print('_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_')
            print("!computer win! score it's for computer!")
            pc_score += 1
        else:
            print('_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_')
            print("!you win! score it's for you!")
            player_score += 1
    print('---------------------------------------')
    print("your total score:" + str(player_score))
    print('....................')
    print('computer total score:' + str(pc_score))
    print('---------------------------------------')
if player_score == pc_score:
    print("no one win")
elif player_score > pc_score:
    print("!congratulation! totally you are the winner")
else:
    print("totally pc is the winner")
while True:
    game = input('do you want to play again? (y/n):')
    if game == 'y':
        pass
    else:
        break

I would appreciate you if you can help me in this problem.

Use a while True: loop in the for-loop. If the input is valid, break the loop, if not, print an error message and ask for input again.

But I want to define a range for it

You want to not count that round, or you want to exit the loop when the input is not valid?

You want a range to control the number of games played; a valid game has not been played if the player doesn't enter a valid choice. You need (or rather, really should have) a separate loop to ensure the player makes a valid choice.
